# react loading content even though I am getting a 404 error

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, react-router

I am creating an application in react and in it I am using react router 4.

My routing looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div id="main-container">
        <header id="main-header">
            <TopBar />
            <MainMenu {...this.props} />
        </header>
        <section id="main-content" className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                <Start {...this.props} />
            )} />
            <Route path='/404' component={NotFound404} />

            <Route exact path="/mytenders" render={() => (
                <MyTenders {...this.props} />
            )} />
            <Route exact path="/mytenders/tender:tenderId" render={( match ) => (
                <Tender {...this.props} match={match}/>
            )} />
            <Route exact path="/mytenders/tender:tenderId/chapter:chapterId" render={( match ) => (
                <Chapter {...this.props} match={match}/>
            )} />
            <Route exact path="/othertenders" render={() => (
                <OthersTenders {...this.props} />
            )} />
            <Route exact path="/recycled" render={() => (
                <Bin {...this.props} />
            )} />
        </section>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but when I try to access /mytenders/tender3/chapter1, I get a 404 error in my console:

```
GET http://localhost:3006/mytenders/tender3/chapter1 404 (Not Found)
```

But as you can see in the picture below, everything is loaded...

[image: screenshot of page and network tab]

I know that something iffy is going on since I cannot seem to be able to save to my database from this page either.

Comment: Change router to `mytenders/tender/:tenderId/chapter/:chapterId` and access it using: `GET http://localhost:3006/mytenders/tender/3/chapter/1`

Comment: I'm still getting the same error `1:1 GET http://localhost:3006/mytenders/tender/3/chapter/1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did you change `<Route exact path="/mytenders/tender:tenderId/chapter:chapterId"` to `<Route exact path="/mytenders/tender/:tenderId/chapter/:chapterId"` ?

Comment: yes, i did change it to that, the url is correct and the data loads, but if you look at the image you see that the same url is loaded twice, once with the content type "document", once with the type "text/html"... I am beginning to believe that that is where the error lies, but I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: is it possible for you to paste more code, pertaining to your index and Chapter file?

Comment: @Winter did you end up having any luck with this? Experiencing the same issue

Comment: @Rustang Do you have any luck with this? Experiencing the same

Comment: Sorry @SantiagoMendozaRamirez,  I don't recall at this point :(